# Java works not well after upgrage Mac OS to Big Sur(v11.0.1)

Tags: java, macos

**Background:**

I use Macbook pro to develop java app, it works well. While, after i upgraded mac os from 10.x to the latest version `Big Sur`, `mvn clean package` threw below exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project dq-common: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[ERROR]   /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/../lib/tools.jar
[ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
[ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
[ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
[ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
```

`java -version`:

```
jingxingdeMacBook-Pro:~ kevin$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_271"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)
jingxingdeMacBook-Pro:dt-center-valid-4.0 kevin$
```

`which java` was changed after upgraded:

before:

```
ingxingdeMacBook-Pro:bin kevin$ which java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

now:

```
jingxingdeMacBook-Pro:~ kevin$ which java
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

`cat ~/.bash_profile`:

```
jingxingdeMacBook-Pro:~ kevin$ cat ~/.bash_profile
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.6.3
#Mac OSX 10.5 or later version need this configure
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
#export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home
export MySQL_HOME=/usr/local/mysql
export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:.
export HADOOP_HOME=/Users/kevin/Desktop/Developments/Software/hadoop-3.3.0
PATH=$M2_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$MySQL_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH:.
export PATH
```

**Question:**

Why `which java` output was changed after i upgraded Mac os, how to fix it.

Comment: may be softlink to `java` is changed after an upgrade, you can reinstall and use sdkmanager to manage multiple java versions on macosx.

Comment: @dkb mac os changed the softlink `$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` after upgraded, i re-install jdk and update $JAVA_JHOME， now it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Reason:** In `~/.bash_profile`, `JAVA_HOME= $(/usr/libexec/java_home)`, after upgraded, $(/usr/libexec/java_home) link to `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java` which doesn't exist in my disk, so jdk is missing.

**Solution:** I delete jdk in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` and reinstall jdk8, and then set `JAVA_HOME` as:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home`

instead of soft link and `source ~/.bash_profile` to let it work.

My full settings:

```
kevinMacBook-Pro:bin kevin$ cat ~/.bash_profile
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.6.3
#Mac OSX 10.5 or later version need this configure
#export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
#Mac 11 need this configure
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home
export MySQL_HOME=/usr/local/mysql
```

Now, jdk works, after mac os upgraded, it indeed update the soft link of `$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` and link to a not existed link, so i think you don't need to delete your jdk, just **update env variables** and **re-open terminal** to check if jdk reset correctly.

Comment: did you have the complete path ending in /java or ending in /bin   I tried this by putting the full path in the .bash_profile ending in java and it results in an error

Comment: Hi TKP, try update JAVA_HOME to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home`

Answer (score 0):

Find you JDK location (mine was `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home`).

1. In terminal `vim ~/.bash_profile` (resp. edit the file in any way you're used to)
2. Add a line exporting your JDK location (in my case it was `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home`)
3. In terminal `source ~/.bash_profile`
4. In terminal `echo $JAVA_HOME` to make sure the environment variable is set properly